# Possible to sort iTunes Artists View not by Album? (iTunes 12/macOS Sierra)

Tags: macos, itunes, music

I have many music tracks on my computers which are free downloads from SoundCloud. They usually don't have all the proper ID3 meta-data.

In iTunes 12 (released with macOS Sierra), is there a way to sort the "Artist" view, ***not*** by Album?

Almost every single Web DL track will have the header "Unknown Album" which feels a tad bit ugly and useless.

[image]

On the image below, I'm in the "Artists" view of an iTunes Remote Library. I've looked around at View Options and some other obscure buttons sprinkled here in there in the iTunes UI, but can't find a way to disable these headers and just display the tracks themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the proper ID3 meta-data, you can simply *select the tracks* you want to put in same album, then <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and change the *artist* or *album artist* to make them fall into the same album. Example: name both the artist and album artist of all the selected tracks, "Soundcloud".

Or you can select Songs on the left pane, then click on Name, Artist, Album, etc. column headers to sort them according to your choice. :)

[image: Music list]

Comment: Thanks, yes it's of course possible to 'fix' the issue by assigning ID3 Albums using iTunes or some third-party software. But unfortunately that involves a lot of work...

Comment: But yeah, maybe I should just set all Unknowns from Soundcloud to the album "Soundcloud". Thanks for the idea.

Comment: No its very quickly. If you have a folder with all your free downloads, delete all these songs from your iTunes (not move to trash) then re-add them to your iTunes. Sort by Date Added, (if you dont see it, right click on column header and tick Date Added) then select all the songs you just added, cmd+i once, then give it an artist + album artist of Soundcloud, save. This will throw all of them into 1 album.